# 2d array populating stops abruptly

Tags: arrays, 2d, populate

I have a simple html with two forms, each with four input fields:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
<title>Test3</title>
</head>

<body> 

<h1>Two Forms</h1>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="test.php">

    <label for="name">F1 Name*</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
    <br/>

    <label for="phone">*Phone*</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"/>
    <br/>

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
    <br/>

    <label for="postcode">*Postcode</label>
    <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" class="input-textfield"/>
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
<br/><br/>


<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="test.php">

    <label for="name2">F2 Name*</label>
    <input type="text" name="name2" id="name2"/>
    <br/>

    <label for="phone2">*Phone*</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone2" id="phone2"/>
    <br/>

    <label for="email2">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email2" id="email2"/>
    <br/>

    <label for="postcode2">*Postcode</label>
    <input type="text" name="postcode2" id="postcode2" class="input-textfield"/>
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Submit" />

</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="check-form.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and I'm trying to insert a paragraph before each form and a span after each input field for displaying messages:

```
var nlForms = []; var arPForSubmitMsg = []; // 1d arrays for forms.

var arNlInputs = new Array([]); // 2d arrays for inputs.
var darSpanForErrorMsg = new Array([]); // 2d arrays for inputs.

window.onload = initialise;

function initialise() {

// for creating and inputing paragraph and span elements for displaying submit and error messages.
nlForms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');    
for (f = 0; f < nlForms.length; f++) {
    arNlInputs[f] = nlForms[f].getElementsByTagName("input"); // store list into array makeing it double.
}

// create paragraph elements of class 'submitmsg'and insert them before each form.
for (f = 0; f < nlForms.length; f++) {
    arPForSubmitMsg[f] = document.createElement('p');
    arPForSubmitMsg[f].setAttribute('class', 'submitmsg');
    arPForSubmitMsg[f].innerHTML = "hello form " + f;
    var nodeFormParent = nlForms[f].parentNode;
    nodeFormParent.insertBefore(arPForSubmitMsg[f], nlForms[f]);
}

// create span elements of class 'errormsg' and
// insert them after each input which is required or needs to be validated.     

for (f = 0; f < nlForms.length; f++) {

    for (i=0; i < arNlInputs[f].length; i++) {

// STOP - here it stops when f=1 and i=0 (it does get inside this for loop)

        darSpanForErrorMsg[f][i] = document.createElement("span");

// but it doesn't get to this point when f=1 and i=0;

        darSpanForErrorMsg[f][i].innerHTML = "hello span " + i;
        darSpanForErrorMsg[f][i].class = "errormsg";

        var nodeInputParent = arNlInputs[f][i].parentNode;
        var nodeInputNextSibling = arNlInputs[f][i].nextSibling ;
        nodeInputParent.insertBefore(darSpanForErrorMsg[f][i], nodeInputNextSibling);

    }
}


} // end initialise().
```

Fields for the first form are populated nicely, but not for the second one. I have checked and the code stops when it gets inside the second for loop to start iteration again when f=1 and i=0. I'm baffeled and cannot get my had around what is happening here. I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (after a long night) :-) :

Even though 2D arrays are declared as 2D (with = array([]); ), still each element within the array needs to be declared as an array to make it 2D. Thus the line of code that is missing is:

```
darSpanForErrorMsg[f] = [];
```

and it should be placed as the first line within the first for loop. Beginner error; I hope it will help someone else that gets stuck with it.